# Arabic characters in functions definitions

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, arabic

I am working on a kind of small project using C# forms which requires all texts written in Arabic characters so when I click on some to create Click Event Handler some Arabic characters may goes on function name definition just like this:

```
private void تفريغالخاناتToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code goes here
}
```

so I am wondering if this kind of functions names could cause a serious problem in future if this program runs on different machines while installing or running ?! on the other hand, I'm working on and compiling it without any problem on my own machine.

Would you recommend me to change these names to English characters so no nightmares in future, or C# can handle it without any danger ?

Comment: What does the language the user see has to do with the language used in the code? This can cause problems with some external tools, but should be technically safe... But i would stick strictly to English.

Comment: Technically this will not cause any issues, however if you would like to work with other devs, do outsourcing or have clients from abroad then you should use english method names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work on every machine since even though some compilers don't support Unicode, the CLR doesn't mind...

Yet... you shouldn't want to code in any not English language because it's a bad convention (There are many articles which explain why coding without proper conventions is bad, and will cause bugs and harder-to-debug-and-write code).

Keep in mind that some coding assistance programs and dis-assemblers (like Reflector and Resharper) might not work properly (maybe those specific two will...).

Also, using reflection on those methods will make you have to consider your way of string comparison, etc...